# case statement in MS Access query give error

Tags: ms-access

I am using below query in Ms Access. And this gives me error `Syntax error in your query expression CASE WHEN not ...` . Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? In Sql Server 2008 R2, the `case` statement runs correctly.

```
SELECT TableApron.RadButtonNo, TableApron.ShortName, QueryForNot1.InspectionDate, QueryForNot1.Findings, QueryForNot1.Status, QueryForNot1.Initials, TableApron.DeptName, TableApron.Lost, TableApron.InServelDate, TableApron.RemovedDate, TableApron.PrivateUserName, TableApron.PrivateUserEmail, TableApron.ApronType, TableApron.Manufacturer
FROM TableApron LEFT JOIN QueryForNot1 ON TableApron.RadButtonNo=QueryForNot1.RadButtonNoI
WHERE (((TableApron.Lost)="N" Or (TableApron.Lost)=[@Lost]) And ((TableApron.InServelDate) Is Null Or (TableApron.InServelDate) Between CDATE([@From]) And CDATE([@To]) Or (TableApron.InServelDate)<CDATE([@To])) And ((TableApron.RemovedDate) Is Null Or (TableApron.RemovedDate) Between CDATE([@From]) And CDATE([@To]) Or (TableApron.RemovedDate)>CDATE([@To])))
ORDER BY
CASE
       WHEN not TableApron.RadButtonNo like '%[^0-9]%' THEN CONVERT(int,TableApron.RadButtonNo)
       WHEN TableApron.RadButtonNo like '[0-9]%' THEN CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(TableApron.RadButtonNo,1,PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',TableApron.RadButtonNo)-1))
    END,
    CASE
       WHEN not TableApron.RadButtonNo like '%[^0-9]%' THEN NULL
       WHEN TableApron.RadButtonNo like '[0-9]%' THEN SUBSTRING(TableApron.RadButtonNo,PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',TableApron.RadButtonNo),9000)
       ELSE TableApron.RadButtonNo
    END;
```

Comment: CASE is T-SQL. Replace with an IIf(condition, true, false) expression.

Answer (score 1):

The `CASE` statement triggers the *first* reported error because it is not supported in Access SQL.  Use `IIf()` instead as @Gustav suggested.

However then you will encounter additional errors because `CONVERT`, `SUBSTRING`, and `PATINDEX` are also not supported in Access SQL.

Instead of `CONVERT`, use `CInt()` to cast a value to Access Integer or `CLng()` for Long Integer.  Or you could use `Val()` and let Access decide which numeric datatype to give you.

Instead of `SUBSTRING`, use `Mid()`.

Instead of `PATINDEX`, use `InStr()`.

Assuming those suggestions eliminate the syntax errors, you may still have an issue with the `Like` wildcard.

If you will be running the query from the query designer or elsewhere under DAO, Access expects `*` instead of `%` as the wildcard.  `%` is the correct wild card only when the query is run from ADO/OleDb.